# JavaScript - How to use JS snippet to inject other code in a page

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, code-snippets

**CONTEXT**

I am building a Meteor/React web app and want to give users a JS Snippet which they can paste inside their site's head and which then gives me the ability to send and receive data as well as to execute certain functions on their site from outside the site.

**QUESTION**

What is the best method to generate such a snippet? What exactly would the snippet do to send/receive information or code from/to my web-app?

Comment: What do you mean with "paste inside their site's"? In a `<textarea>` on the page? Or do the users edit the HTML source and open the page locally? Or maybe as a Greasemonkey script?

Comment: There is a lot involved to this. I won't post a full solution, but this might help get you started https://www.coshx.com/blog/2015/02/19/developing-an-embeddable-javascript-widget-snippet-for-client-sites/

search around for embedabble javascript widget tutorials. Hope this at least gets you in the right direction.

Comment: @C14L - sorry, i had put <head> but it didn't show up.

Comment: @steezeburger - thank you for pointing me in the right direction, that's exactly what I needed at this point!